# Instrumental Variables - Exogeneity Tests using region characteristics

Tags: microeconomics, econometrics, applied-econometrics, instrumental-variable

I am using IV methods to establish the causality, I want to run some exogeniety tests. I have been going over Woolridge (Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data, 2010) and I am not entirely certain if my understanding in this is correct.

If I have Individual data on outcome, $Y_ip$, province level endogenous treatment variable $D_p$, $Z_p$ (instrument also at province level) and $X_p$ controls at the province level. There are also some individual level controls.  I would like to do some exogeniety tests to see if the provinces where instrument levels are high are different from provinces where instrument levels are low.

So the first-stage specification is as follows

$D_{ip}$ = $\beta_0+ \beta_1 Z_p + \alpha_p X_p + \epsilon_ip$

Second Stage:

$Y_{ip} = \gamma_0+ \gamma_1 \widehat{D_p} + \zeta_p X_p + \varepsilon_ip$

I want to now test whether provinces with high instrument levels differ from provinces with low levels of the instrument by running the same IV on province level characteristics ($X_p) before endogenous variables' date of measurement. My rationale is that if I get insignificant results for provincial characteristics, the exogeneity test holds in that the districts do not differ before the treatment.

Comment: My guess would be that, as you are controlling for $X_p$ in both regressions, it is ok to have correlation between $Z_p$ and $X_p$. Of course, $Z_p$ could be correlated with unobserved province level characteristics (that are in $\varepsilon_{i,p}$) which would make the IV approach invalid. Unfortunately, this cannot be tested as they are by definition unobserved.

Comment: Why does this have the `microeconomics` tag?

Comment: In your first step, you should test for $\beta_1=0$. If this hypothesis cannot be rejected, you have weak instruments $Z_p$ and your second stage parameters are poorly identified. (By the way, it is quite curious to have the same random term in both regressions, can you develop this point?)